# How should HTTP server implementation handle internal errors?

Tags: http, error-handling, streaming, runtime-error

I'm implementing a simple HTTP server. Since I expect the amount of data per request to be quite large, it would make sense for me to send response in smaller chunks, so that clients are able to process data continuously as a stream and don't need to wait for the last bit.

Eager as I may be to try this out, there is one thing troubling me: What should I do when the server encounters an error after portion of the response has already been transmitted to the client? Is there any HTTP mechanism to tell the client to discard the part of the response which has arrived so far?

Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP itself probably doesn't have anything to help you here, but you could simply tweak your your stream's format/protocol so that you could send status/error codes over it. For example, start every chunk with a status code.

Comment: Interesting idea. So, overall the server would return code 200, but the individual chunks would contain information whether they're good or bad. That'll do!